# Reducing the Amount of Duplicate Code when Mapping DTOs in Go

Tags: go

I'm currently learning go, and I'd appreciate people's insight on how to best reduce the amount of duplicated code.

Folder structure for the relevant part is this:

```
.
├── http
│   ├── handlers
│   └── routes
├── models
│   └── dto
├── specifications
└── store
    └── postgres
```

In my `specifications` folder, I have 2 'store' interfaces:

```
type TaskStore interface {
    CreateTask(ctx context.Context, input dto.TaskCreate) error
    UpdateTask(ctx context.Context, id int, input dto.TaskUpdate) error
    GetTask(ctx context.Context, id int) (dto.TaskResult, error)
    ListTasks(ctx context.Context) ([]dto.TaskResult, error)
    DeleteTask(ctx context.Context, id int) error
}

type TagStore interface {
    CreateTag(ctx context.Context, input dto.TagCreate) error
    RenameTag(ctx context.Context, id int, input dto.TagUpdate) error
    ListTags(ctx context.Context) ([]dto.TagResult, error)
    GetTag(ctx context.Context, id int) (dto.TagResult, error)
    DeleteTag(ctx context.Context, id int) error
}
```

The the `store/postgres` folder contains implementations for both tasks and tags (repository pattern).

The problem I'm seeing:

In my `handlers` folder I have a struct that takes an input of one of the store interfaces:

```
type TaskHandler struct {
    store specifications.TaskStore
}

func NewTaskHandler(store specifications.TaskStore) TaskHandler {
    return TaskHandler{
        store: store,
    }
}
```

```
type TagHandler struct {
    store specifications.TagStore
}

func NewTagHandler(store specifications.TagStore) TagHandler {
    return TagHandler{
        store: store,
    }
}
```

And these handlers contain methods that will map to api paths:

```
func (h TaskHandler) List() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        tasks, err := h.store.ListTasks(r.Context())
        if err != nil {
            log.Err(err).Msg("failed to retrieve tasks")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        render.JSON(w, r, tasks)
    }
}
```

```
func (h TagHandler) List() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        tags, err := h.store.ListTags(r.Context())
        if err != nil {
            log.Err(err).Msg("failed to retrieve tags")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        render.JSON(w, r, tags)
    }
}
```

You'll notice that the `List` method on each handler is basically identical, with the exception of the interface being used by each store.

How can I change this so that there is less duplicated code?

I initially thought I could use generics to solve this, with something like:

```
type EntityStore[CreateDto any, UpdateDto any, ResultDto any] interface {
    Create(ctx context.Context, input CreateDto) error
    Update(ctx context.Context, id int, input UpdateDto) error
    List(ctx context.Context) ([]ResultDto, error)
    Get(ctx context.Context, id int) (ResultDto, error)
    Delete(ctx context.Context, id int) error
}
```

But this would then mean mapping each type into the handlers, and I don't think this is a practical solution.

Any suggestions on how to better map my DTO's and interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a helper function

```
func ListHandler[T any](name string, lister func(ctx context.Context) ([]T, error)) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        list, err := lister(r.Context())
        if err != nil {
            log.Err(err).Msg("failed to retrieve " + name)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        render.JSON(w, r, list)
    }
}
```

and then you would have

```
func (h TaskHandler) List() http.HandlerFunc {
    return ListHandler("tasks", h.store.ListTasks)
}

func (h TagHandler) List() http.HandlerFunc {
    return ListHandler("tags", h.store.ListTags)
}
```